Synapse analytics - Workspace packages - Unable to upload - ortools.whl


 pip:
  - pip ortools==9.7.2996
channels:
- nodefaults
24/09/30 02:16:14 INFO Updating environment

2024-09-30 02:16:14,783 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: 24/09/30 02:16:14 INFO Running /usr/lib/miniforge3/bin/conda config --set always_softlink false

2024-09-30 02:16:15,253 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: 24/09/30 02:16:15 INFO 

2024-09-30 02:16:15,253 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: 24/09/30 02:16:15 INFO Ran /usr/lib/miniforge3/bin/conda config --set always_softlink false successfully
24/09/30 02:16:15 INFO Running /usr/lib/miniforge3/bin/conda config --set always_copy true

2024-09-30 02:16:15,739 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: 24/09/30 02:16:15 INFO 

2024-09-30 02:16:15,739 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: 24/09/30 02:16:15 INFO Ran /usr/lib/miniforge3/bin/conda config --set always_copy true successfully
24/09/30 02:16:15 INFO Running /usr/lib/miniforge3/bin/conda env update -p /home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv --file /usr/lib/library-manager/bin/lmjob/BDARAphSparkpl/package_cleaned_environment.yml

2024-09-30 02:17:11,447 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'pip ortools==9.7.2996' (from line 1 of /usr/lib/library-manager/bin/lmjob/BDARAphSparkpl/condaenv.3js5lcnr.requirements.txt)


2024-09-30 02:17:11,448 INFO UserConsole [redirect output]: 
CondaEnvException: Pip failed



In Reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-azure-portal-add-libraries
I am unable to upload 'ortools' packages to spark pool. getting the error message
Upload details.
Couldn’t upload files to workspace.
Failed.
Synapse workspace ==> Mange == > Workspace packages == > Upload
or Spark pool ==> Packages == > workspace packages.
.whl file attached

I have tried the below approach:
Create a requirment.txt file with the version for ortools like below:

I have created the .yml file like below:
name: my_spark_pool_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip
  - pip:
    - ortools==9.7.2996

Results:

In side the text file as an example I have choosed below version for ortools:
ortools==9.7.2996

Then I have uploaded requirment.txt to the spark pool using the below steps:



Once the file is uploaded to the spark pool.
You can check if the ortools pacakge is successfully installed? with below code:
import os
os.system("pip show ortools")

Results:
Name: ortools
Version: 9.7.2996
Summary: Google OR-Tools python libraries and modules
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/optimization/
Author: Google LLC
Author-email: or-tools@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, numpy, protobuf
Required-by: 
0


I create requirement.txt and uploaded at requirement folder under packages ..its did some process and returned below error. ","isSessionTimedOut":null,"isStreamingQueryExists":"false","impulseErrorCode":"Spark_Ambiguous_NonJvmUserApp_ExitWithStatus1","impulseTsg":null,"impulseClassification":"Ambiguous"},"state":"dead","log":["ERROR: No matching distribution found for ortools==9.7.2996","","",

"CondaEnvException: Pip failed","","24/09/30 01:21:24 ERROR b"Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies. Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place. Please add an explicit pip dependency. I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.

\nCollecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done\nSolvingenvironment: ...working... done\nPreparing transaction: ...working... done\nVerifying transaction: ...working... done\nExecuting transaction: ...working... done\nInstalling pip dependencies: ...working...

Ran pip subprocess with arguments:\n['/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/clonedenv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/usr/lib/library-manager/bin/lmjob/BDARAphSparkpl/condaenv.c95vg6vv.requirements.txt']\nPip subprocess output:\n\nfailed\n"","24/09/30 01:21:24 INFO Cleanup following folders and files from staging directory:","24/09/30 01:21:31

Can you add code like below in the requirment.txt and check once?
pip
ortools==9.7.2996

!pip install ortools==9.7.2996
In your note also you can try the above code to install the pacakge

FYI
My Apache spark version 3.3 and python version 3.10

still the problem is same, see the error in the code snippet attachment.

Mine is spark version 3.4 and python version 3.10.
!pip install ortools==9.7.2996 have tried this?

!pip install ortools==9.7.2996, ran from notebook ... getting below error ......WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa0c7a024d0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ortools/

@Madhu Tallapaneni approaches using requirment.txt , pip  command both worked for me. I also have tried using .yml file format to install the package I have updated the solution please check and let me know if you any issues

-- It seems there is network related issue. not able to communicate services outside traffic.
simple request not working
test_url = "https://www.google.com"
response = requests.get(test_url)
print("Google Response Code:", response.status_code)
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7faccbae2650>, 'Connection to www.google.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

FYI - comments are not for long discussions; they are for clarifications. Also, they are definitely not the place to post code/data/errors (as it's unformatted and impossible to edit). This is even more important with Python, since spacing is critical. Any updates need to be edited as part of the question, not as a series of code-filled comments.
